# Sun Directory Server 5.2 performance

Tags: performance, ldap, metrics, logging, sun-one

I'm using logconv.pl (provided by Sun), to measure performance on my server.

These two metrics results, are worrying me a bit:

Binds:                        192164
   Unbinds:                      111569

In fact the difference between the two it's quite big, how can I determine which are the unbound requests?

As stated by Lodovic:

> Many applications just close the
>   connections without sending an Unbind
>   request. This simply can explain the
>   difference.

But the logconv.pl doesn't show details about the unbound requests, do you know any other tools or can you suggest some queries or whatever that can help me find out the root cause?

Do you think anyway that the performances may improve fixing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many applications just close the connections without sending an Unbind request. This simply can explain the difference.
Also, in case of protocol errors, or idle connections, the server may shutdown the connection, in which case there is no Unbind requests.
Finally, any network error that closes the TCP connection will prevent the client from closing the LDAP session with the Unbind request.

I hope this helps.

Regards,

Ludovic.

Comment: Thanks, I hope the first case ;-) It would be nice to know if there are log analyzer that can find out which bind are not unbound